# Getting an error while trying to call for a child component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am building a RegisterScreen for my app and I have this child component called `LogResContainer' where I have a component that I share between my login and my register screens.

The thing is I think I am calling everything as it should be called and I don't know what's wrong anymore.

Here is the RegisterScreen.js:

```
import { 
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    StyleSheet,
    Text, 
    TextInput, 
    TouchableOpacity, 
    View 
} from 'react-native'
import React, {useState}from 'react'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../firebase.js';
import { styles } from '../styles/styles.js';
import {LogResContainer} from './LogResContainer.js';

const RegisterScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const handleSignup = () => {
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then(userCredential => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
            console.log(user.email);
        })
        .catch(error => alert(error.message));
    }

    console.log(setEmail);
    console.log(setPassword);
    console.log(handleSignup);
    console.log("Registrar");

  return (
    <LogResContainer 
        setEmail={setEmail}
        setPassword={setPassword}
        type='Registrar'
        func={handleSignup}
    />
    );
}

export default RegisterScreen
```

And here is LogResContainer.js:

```
import {styles} from '../styles/styles.js';

export default LogResContainer = ({setEmail, setPassword, type, func}) => {

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding">
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          style={styles.input}
          secureTextEntry
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={func} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{type}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};
```

I have studied the props docs and looked at multiple youtube videos but I am pretty much exhausted. Don't know what I am missing.

Comment: These errors are catchable via a linter. Setting up eslint in your editor will save you a ton of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You export `LogResContainer` as default export, but try to import it like a named export.

Either change the export to a named export:

```
export const LogResContainer = () => <>"I am a named export"</>
```

Or change the import to import the default:

```
import LogResContainer from "./LogResContainer.js"
```

And if you don't know the difference between named and default exports, read it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-export-default-in-javascript/

And please add the errors you get, so we can help you better.

Comment: I will do, thank you very much <3

Comment: @OneWinterSigh Yupp, if you improve your question, I can give it an upvote. (I hope you care, because SO is not only getting about help, but getting it in a way, that others who might have the same or a similar problem, can benefit, too)